# Image Quantization with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, libpng

I need to reduce the colors in an image to a specified X number of colors.

I thought it would be quite simple with OpenCV but I was unable to find anything "ready-made", and the solutions proposed on the net were more about DYI from scratch. I don't understand why this issue has to be so complicated.

So I am asking here, what would be the simplest/fastest way to reduce the number of colors in an image to X, and then save it in an indexed PNG?

I tried `kmeans` on a mobile device, using OpenCV for iOS, but it takes more than 1 minute which is too long.

Comment: Read the first part [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35482205/5008845)

Comment: Please quantify *"too long"*. How long is "too long"? Too long for what? How big is your image?

Comment: Updated. Too long is more then 10-20 sec on a modern mobile device. :)

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32698512/2571705) helps.

Comment: Consider using a standalone app such as pngquant to postprocess your image instead of trying to do it within OpenCV.